# C++ copies of objects with abstract class pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class, copy-constructor

Consider the `Container` class, which basically stores a vector of `unique_ptr`s of `Box` objects and can perform some computations on them.

```
class Container
{
  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Box> > boxes_;
  public:
    Container(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Box> > &&boxes): boxes_(std::move(boxes)){}
    double TotalVolume() { /* Iterate over this->boxes_ and sum */ }
};
```

Here, `Box` is an abstract class that has a pure virtual method such as `double Box::Volume()`.

Now, suppose that I instantiate a container in the main program as:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Box> > x;
x.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<Box>(new SquareBox(1.0)));
x.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<Box>(new RectangularBox(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)));
Container c(x);
```

How do I make copies of `c`? I would like a function that makes copies of the underlying `Box` object in `boxes_`, but I think it's hard to do this with base classes?

Comment: Anyway, why don't you use std::vector<Box>?

Comment: Thanks: C'tor changed. As for not using a `vector<Box>`, `Container`, is, in fact, a derived class of some base class that has a virtual `TotalVolume` method. My original problem is not boxes and containers, but some complicated project that I'm trying to extend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to make your copies is to have a "Copy" virtual method in your base class.  This method would create a copy of the current object and return a (unique) pointer to it.  If there are any contained pointers within the class, they'd need new copies created as well (a deep copy).

Other approaches exist.  For instance, you could test each object in the vector to determine its type (using `dynamic_cast`), but this is ugly, inefficient, and very error prone.

Comment: That actually works pretty well for my situation. Is there a name for this design pattern (copy method with `unique_ptr`s)?

Comment: @Salmonstrikes: The common name is a **clone** function. One of the old gurus called it a **virtual constructor**, but while that term is in the ISO C++ FAQ (or at least was in the original C++ FAQ), it's very rarely, if ever, used. There are even questionnaires designed to test your C++ knowledge that asks why there can be no virtual constructor in C++, thereby exposing both the authors' lack of knowledge (that at one time it was a term used by well-read people) and the authors' lack of reasoning ability (almost anything can be given a meaning when you design a language).