# copy construct a vector of objects of an abstract class that is implemented by a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, abstract-class, copy-constructor

I have an abstract class say `A` which is implemented by a template class say `B`, `B` is specialized for a vector type that implements a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator, but when I compile i get the error: `static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range`. Declaring a virtual copy assignment in the abstract class does not help, as the signature there is: `A & operator=(const A &);` but in B it is implemented for type `B` so the signatures do not match.

**Why I have this weird hierarchy?**
Because I am trying to implement a json parsing library, I need to have a container that can store string, number, bigint, boolean and array types, so I implemented the hierarchy to achieve type erasure, the template type is for these 5 types and need to specialize only for string and vector types.

Actual hierarchy (minimal reproducible example):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <memory>
 #include <iostream>

 class BasicJsonType {
 public:
     virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
     virtual void setNull() = 0;
     // copy assignment method
     // virtual BasicJsonType& operator= (const BasicJsonType &value) = 0;
     ~BasicJsonType() = default;
 };

 template<typename T>
 class BasicJsonTypeInterface: public BasicJsonType {
 protected:
     bool empty = true;

 public:
     virtual const T& get() = 0;
     virtual void set(const T&) = 0;
 };

namespace json {
// json::array is defined as
using array = std::vector<BasicJsonType>;
}

template <typename T>
class JsonValue {
    T x;
public:
    virtual std::string toString() {
        return "";
    }

    virtual const T & get() {
        return this->x;
    }

    virtual void set(const T &value) {
        this->x = value;
    }
};

template<>
class JsonValue<json::array>: public BasicJsonTypeInterface<json::array> {
    std::shared_ptr<json::array> array;

public:
    JsonValue() = delete;

    JsonValue(const JsonValue<json::array> &value): JsonValue(*(value.array)) {
        std::cout << "const JsonValue<json::array> &";
    }

    JsonValue(const json::array &array) {
        std::cout << "const json::array &";
        // error
        this->array.reset(new json::array(array));
    }

    JsonValue(JsonValue<json::array> &&value): JsonValue(static_cast<json::array &&> (*(value.array)))
    { std::cout << "const JsonValue<json::array> &"; }

    JsonValue(json::array &&array) {
        this->array.reset(new json::array(std::move(array)));
        this->empty = false;
    }

    virtual void setNull() { }

    virtual const json::array &get() {
        return *(this->array);
    }

    virtual void set(const json::array &value) {
        this->array.reset(new json::array(value));
     }
};

int main() {}
```

I created the interface type since I wanted to implement the `get`, `set` methods for all the types and irrespective of the type.

I searched for the error, and what I found is I am missing a copy function for the `BasicJsonType`, like what it suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315760/c-copies-of-objects-with-abstract-class-pointers).

There maybe some design flaws in this, since it is my first try with anything of practical use with c++, I am targeting for `c++11`.

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the complete error message in the question

Comment: On a side note: have a look at https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson. It has an API which is almost as optimal as it can get for a json library implemented in C++ IMO. Maybe this can act as inspiration for your project.

Comment: OT: [Each identifier that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#name-3.1.sentence-1).

Comment: A question regarding your design: You'll have `dynamic_cast` the values in `std::vector<_BasicJsonType>` to  `_BasicJsonTypeInterface<T>` sooner or later anyways as far as i can tell. Why don't you cast to `JsonValue<T>` directly and omitt the virtual functions and intermediate classes?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann can you please elaborate the changes?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am trying to reproduce it using a simpler example, but cannot do so, I will update the post as soon I have a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I don't know if it has to be any shorter, but there are things missing. Only now I checked and it seems like all you need to add is the includes (and a dummy declaration of `JsonValue`) to reproduce the error https://godbolt.org/z/cx78rn

Comment: consider that it takes time for others to add the missing includes. Don't get me wrong, but I already spend some time with this quesiton now just to reproduce the error message, would be way simpler if I could just copy paste your code

Comment: If you need to store objects of polymorphic type on a container, they are usually stored as pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`s).

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have updated the post with a reproducible example of the problem, thanks for support

Comment: @bipll, I thought of providing reference semantics for the array like you can in javascript, that is why I used a `shared_ptr`, is there a better way?

Comment: @Nilesh, both are fine, just don't keep objecs of an abstract type simply by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<BasicJsonType>;
```

This is a useless type.

`BasicJsonType` is an abstract class.  Abstract classes are not value types.  `std::vector` stores value types.

`std::vector` expects regular types (or semiregular if you don't need copy).  Abstract types are NOT regular types.

There are a number of ways to have polymorphic regular types, but they all take work or 3rd party libraries.

---

A minor issue:

```
 ~BasicJsonType() = default;
```

this should be virtual.

...

There are a number of ways to approach your problem of getting a regular type to store in `std::vector`.

1. Store `unique_ptr<BasicJsonType>` in your `vector`.  This permits **moving** but not *assignment**.
2. Implement a `value_ptr` (based off unique ptr) that understands how to (virtually) clone its contents when copied.
3. Implement a `cow_ptr` that uses a shared ptr under the hood for immutable data, and does a copy-on-write.
4. Create an `any_with_interface` based off `std::any` that guarantees the stored value matches an interface, and provides `operator->` and `*` that returns that interface.
5. Store a `std::variant` of the various kinds of json concrete types.  Write a helper function to get the abstract interface (if you need it).

---

As your set of supported types is closed (there are only so many json types), #5 is probably easiest.

```
class BasicJsonType {
public:
   virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
   virtual void setNull() = 0;
   virtual bool isNull() const = 0;
protected: // no deleting through this interface
   ~BasicJsonType() = default;
};

// if we find this overload, remember to implement
// your own to_json_string for the type in question
template<class T>
std::string to_json_string( T const& ) = delete;
std::string to_json_string( std::string const& s ) { return s; }
std::string to_json_string( double const& d )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << d;
    return ss.str();
}

template <typename T>
class JsonValue:public BasicJsonType {
public:
  JsonValue() = default;
  JsonValue(JsonValue const&) = default;
  JsonValue(JsonValue &&) = default;
  JsonValue& operator=(JsonValue const&) = default;
  JsonValue& operator=(JsonValue &&) = default;

  JsonValue( T t ):value(std::move(t)) {}

  std::optional<T> value;
  std::string toString() const final {
    if (value)
      return to_json_string(*value);
    else
      return "(null)";
  }
  bool isNull() const final {
    return !static_cast<bool>(value);
  }
  void setNull() final {
    value = std::nullopt;
  }
};
template<class T>
JsonValue(T)->JsonValue<T>;
```

you create a free function `to_json_string` for each `T` you pass to `JsonValue`; if you don't, you get a compile-time error.

The remaining tricky part is making a variant containing a vector of a type depending on the same variant.

```
struct json_variant;
using json_array = std::vector<json_variant>;
struct json_variant :
    std::variant< JsonValue<double>, JsonValue<std::string>, JsonValue<json_array> >
{
    using std::variant< JsonValue<double>, JsonValue<std::string>, JsonValue<json_array> >::variant;
    std::variant< JsonValue<double>, JsonValue<std::string>, JsonValue<json_array> > const& base() const { return *this; }
    std::variant< JsonValue<double>, JsonValue<std::string>, JsonValue<json_array> >& base() { return *this; }
};

BasicJsonType const& getInterface( json_variant const& var )
{
    return std::visit( [](auto& elem)->BasicJsonType const& { return elem; }, var.base());
}
BasicJsonType& getInterface( json_variant& var )
{
    return std::visit( [](auto& elem)->BasicJsonType& { return elem; }, var.base());
}

std::string to_json_string( json_array const& arr )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "{";
    for (auto&& elem:arr)
    {
        ss << getInterface(elem).toString();
        ss << ",";
    }
    ss << "}";
    return ss.str();
}
```

and test code:

```
JsonValue<json_array> bob;
bob.value.emplace();
bob.value->push_back( JsonValue(3.14) );
bob.value->push_back( JsonValue(std::string("Hello world!")) );
std::cout << bob.toString();
```

there we go, a value-semantics Json data type in C++.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/GKaWsK).

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you can use `boost::any` or `boost::variant`.  Everything I did above works with them, except the deduction guide (which is just syntactic sugar).

All of the alternative plans also work; a value pointer, surrendering copy and using unique ptr, a cow pointer, etc.

You can also roll your own any or variant, or find a stand-alone one, if you dislike boost.

---

```
template<class T, class=void>
struct has_clone_method:std::false_type{};
template<class T>
struct has_clone_method<T,
  decltype( void(&T::clone) )
>:std::true_type{};

template<class T,
  typename std::enable_if<!has_clone_method<T>{}, bool>::type = true
>
std::unique_ptr<T> do_clone( T const& t ) {
  return std::make_unique<T>(t);
}
template<class T,
  typename std::enable_if<has_clone_method<T>{}, bool>::type = true
>
std::unique_ptr<T> do_clone( T const& t ) {
  return t.clone();
}

template<class T>
struct value_ptr:std::unique_ptr<T>
{
  using base = std::unique_ptr<T>;
  using base::base;
  using base::operator=;

  value_ptr()=default;
  value_ptr(value_ptr&&)=default;
  value_ptr& operator=(value_ptr&&)=default;

  template<class D,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, D>::value, bool> = true
  >
  value_ptr( value_ptr<D> const& o ):
    base( o?do_clone(*o):nullptr)
  {}
  template<class D,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, D>::value, bool> = true
  >
  value_ptr( value_ptr<D>&& o ):
    base( std::move(o) )
  {}

  value_ptr( base b ):base(std::move(b)) {}

  value_ptr(value_ptr const& o):
    base( o?do_clone(*o):nullptr )
  {}

  value_ptr& operator=(value_ptr const& o) {
    if (!o)
    {
      this->reset();
    }
    else if (this != &o) // test only needed for optimization
    {
      auto tmp = do_clone(*o);
      swap( (base&)*this, tmp );
    }
    return *this;
  }
};
template<class T, class...Args>
value_ptr<T> make_value_ptr( Args&&...args ) {
  std::unique_ptr<T> retval( new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
  return std::move(retval);
}


class BasicJsonType {
public:
   virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
   virtual void setNull() = 0;
   virtual bool isNull() const = 0;
   virtual std::unique_ptr<BasicJsonType> clone() const = 0;
   virtual ~BasicJsonType() = default;
};

using Json = value_ptr<BasicJsonType>;

using JsonVector = std::vector<Json>;

// your own to_json_string for the type in question
template<class T>
std::string to_json_string( T const& ) = delete;
std::string to_json_string( std::string const& s ) { return s; }
std::string to_json_string( double const& d )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << d;
    return ss.str();
}

template <typename T>
class JsonValue:public BasicJsonType {
public:
  JsonValue() = default;
  JsonValue(JsonValue const&) = default;
  JsonValue(JsonValue &&) = default;
  JsonValue& operator=(JsonValue const&) = default;
  JsonValue& operator=(JsonValue &&) = default;

  JsonValue( T t ):value(make_value_ptr<T>(std::move(t))) {}

  value_ptr<T> value;
  std::string toString() const final {
    if (value)
      return to_json_string(*value);
    else
      return "(null)";
  }
  bool isNull() const final {
    return !static_cast<bool>(value);
  }
  void setNull() final {
    value = nullptr;
  }

  std::unique_ptr<BasicJsonType> clone() const final {
    return std::unique_ptr<JsonValue>(new JsonValue(*this));
  }
};

using JsonNumber = JsonValue<double>;
using JsonString = JsonValue<std::string>;
using JsonArray = JsonValue<JsonVector>;

std::string to_json_string( JsonVector const& arr )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "{";
    for (auto&& elem:arr)
    {
        if (elem)
        {
            ss << elem->toString();
        }
        ss << ",";
    }
    ss << "}";
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    JsonArray arr;
    arr.value = make_value_ptr<JsonVector>();
    arr.value->push_back( make_value_ptr<JsonNumber>( 3.14 ));
    arr.value->push_back( make_value_ptr<JsonString>( "Hello World" ));
    std::cout << arr.toString() << "\n";
}
```

here we make `value_ptr`, a smart pointer that supports copy.

It uses `do_clone`, which calls `.clone()` if it exists, and if it does not invokes their copy constructor.  This permits you to make a `value_ptr<T>` where `T` is a value type, or a `value_ptr<T>` where `T` is an abstract type with a `.clone()` method.

I use it for a low-quality "optional" within `JsonValue` itself (a nullable type).

A `JsonVector` is then a vector of `value_ptr<BasicJsonType>`.

A `BasicJsonType` is implemented in `JsonValue`, where it stores it data in turn in a `value_ptr<T>`.

---

An iterative improvement would be to move the polymorphism to an internal detail.

Have a `JsonValue` that stores a `value_ptr` to a `JsonBase`.  The `JsonStorage<T>` class implements `JsonBase`, and is not itself nullable.

`JsonValue` knows all 4 types that it can be.  It provides interfaces that try-to-get the value of a specific type, and fail if you ask for the wrong type.

This reduces indirection, and gives the result that there isn't a NULL of type double, string, array that is distinct.

```
class JsonData {
public:
   virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
   virtual std::unique_ptr<JsonData> clone() const = 0;
   virtual ~JsonData() = default;
};

using JsonPoly = value_ptr<JsonData>;

template<class T>
class JsonStorage:public JsonData {
public:
  T value;
  std::string toString() const final {
    return to_json_string(value);
  }
  JsonStorage( T t ):value(std::move(t)) {}

  JsonStorage() = default;
  JsonStorage( JsonStorage const& )=default;
  JsonStorage( JsonStorage && )=default;
  JsonStorage& operator=( JsonStorage const& )=default;
  JsonStorage& operator=( JsonStorage && )=default;

  std::unique_ptr<JsonData> clone() const final {
    return std::unique_ptr<JsonStorage>(new JsonStorage(*this));
  }
};

struct JsonValue {
    JsonValue() = default;
    JsonValue( JsonValue const& ) = default;
    JsonValue( JsonValue && ) = default;
    JsonValue& operator=( JsonValue const& ) = default;
    JsonValue& operator=( JsonValue && ) = default;

    explicit operator bool() { return static_cast<bool>(data); }

    std::string toString() const {
        if (!data)
            return "(null)";
        else
            return data->toString();
    }
    template<class T>
    T* get() {
      if (!data) return nullptr;
      JsonStorage<T>* pValue = dynamic_cast<JsonStorage<T>*>(data.get());
      if (!pValue) return nullptr;
      return &(pValue->value);
    }
    template<class T>
    T const* get() const {
      if (!data) return nullptr;
      JsonStorage<T> const* pValue = dynamic_cast<JsonStorage<T>*>(data.get());
      if (!pValue) return nullptr;
      return &(pValue->value);
    }

    JsonValue( double d ):
        data( make_value_ptr<JsonStorage<double>>(d))
    {}
    JsonValue( std::string s ):
        data( make_value_ptr<JsonStorage<std::string>>(s))
    {}
    JsonValue( char const* str ):
        data( make_value_ptr<JsonStorage<std::string>>(str))
    {}
    JsonValue( std::initializer_list<JsonValue> );
private:
  value_ptr<JsonData> data;
};

using JsonVector = std::vector<JsonValue>;
std::string to_json_string( JsonVector const& arr )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "{";
    for (auto&& elem:arr)
    {
        ss << elem.toString();
        ss << ",";
    }
    ss << "}";
    return ss.str();
}

JsonValue::JsonValue( std::initializer_list<JsonValue> il ):
    data( make_value_ptr<JsonStorage<JsonVector>>( il ))
{}


int main() {
    JsonValue arr = {JsonValue{3.14}, JsonValue{"Hello World"}};
    std::cout << arr.toString() << "\n";
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/z5Yd43).

Here, given a `JsonValue v` (not a template), you can ask `v.get<double>()` which returns a pointer-to-double if and only if the value contains a double.

`JsonValue v = 3.14` works, as does `JsonValue str = "hello"`.

Adding new types requires a `to_json_string` overload, and that the type supported be regular.

`JsonValue` is a polymorphic value type.  The virtual stuff is all implementation details, not exposed to the end user.  We do type erasure internally.  It is basically a `std::any`, with an extra `toString` method.

Comment: I was aware of any and variant, it is just i wanted to support c++11 and above

Comment: @Nilesh `boost` has `boost::any` and `boost::variant`.  The fundamental issue is that abstract types are not value types.  You need a regular or semiregular type to put into a vector.

Comment: I am doing this to learn some concepts so I am refraining from using any libraries beside the standard library, this may be complex and time consuming which is fine. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Nilesh Sure!  The "I don't support copy out of the box" unique_ptr one is a good plan.  Then you can either write value_ptr, or manually implement copy in your json array code.  You'll need a `clone` method in the interface, and you'll need a public virtual destructor in the interface as well.

Comment: I will try with this approach. Can you please edit the answer and elaborate this approach. All this is new to me so an elaborate answer will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Nilesh Two implementations.  Go forth and learn!  :)

Comment: Hi, I tried to tear down your approach, I understand the individual peices but I dont get the bigger picture. The only part I can understand completely is the value_ptr and how it helps achieving a value semantics based json implementation. But why the type JsonStorage is needed I dont get it, and how does the complete system achieved the goal. If you be kind enough explain the abstract logic of what is needed why and how they achieve what they are doing, or atleast point to some resource I should go through for these concepts, it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Nilesh Assuming the last one.  `JsonData`/`JsonStorage<T>` are implementation details that allow `JsonValue` to act polymophically while being a value type itself, and  C++ is much more friendly to value types than reference types.  `JsonData` provides the abstract interface, while `JsonStorage<T>` implements it for each Json data type.

Comment: If I get it right JsonValue is a value type(reason being it owns data through value_ptr), but it has to be a polymorphic type to store different types, thus value_ptr is of an abstract type, JsonData which is an interface for JsonStorage that is the actual container which also provides a cloning method required by the value_ptr

Comment: @Nilesh Yes.  Then we use built in C++ RTTI and dynamic cast to determine if our JsonValue matches the type passed to `get<T>`, and if it does, we return a pointer to the value.  We return a pointer, so we can fail (returning nullptr) if the type is wrong.  This pointer doesn't own the data, and is intended for short-term use, like `if (double* pval = json.get<double>()) { // use *pval in this if expression }`

Comment: Yes, now I atleast understand the whole thing. I was trying to add json object as std::map to this. I think adding a constructor: `JsonValue(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, JsonValue>>)` and an overloaded subscript operator `JsonValue* operator[](std::string)` will do this. But I was thinking if it is semantically correct to add a `operator[]` when JsonValue is a polymorphic type and not all the data it stores will support it? I have added an overload in the CompilerExplorer page you shared it is essentially the `get()` function for JsonValue type.

Comment: @nilesh It is ok to say "Can I look up in you with this key" where the operation can fail.  But (X->LookupAble->OptY) can also be written (X->OptLookupAble->Y) if you get my drift; is it more useful to ask if it can be looked into before you try to look into it, or just try and have it maybe fail?  It probably depends.

Comment: yeah I get your point, and a possibly failing implementation seems fine. But I was curious if it is possible to check whether the `operator[]()` method exists on the type, I was trying something like your implementation for `has_clone` and use `std::enable_if` for `operator[]()` method but JsonValue is not a template type so I stopped there.

Comment: @Nilesh `JsonValue`'s runtime type varies -- it is polymorphic -- so compile time tests if `[]` exists fundamentally cannot produce useful information.  Json's "values" are polymorphic; this is a way to make polymorphic value types in C++.